# set html in tinymce editor

Tags: html, tinymce

i am trying to set HTML data in tinymce using jquery. But i have some problem in it.

my html data is as :

```
  var data = "<div><img src='http://localhost/images/test.png' /><div>Image Title</div></div> html";
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(data , {format : 'raw'} );
```

It renders the div and image properly. but i get additional

tag  with html in it
If i remove the html word the data is not properly rendered in editor

I also tried various below combination, but it did not helped:

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.setHTML(tinyMCE.activeEditor.id, str);
tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(data );
```

Answer (score 2):

Tinymce and the browser taking care of the validity of the html entered.Can you show me the editor content after you entered your data?

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(content);
```

is the usual correct way to replace the current editor content with the text that the content variable hold.

Comment: Is there no way to force tinyMCE to set html? Because I use it in a modal dialog and have several textareas on my site. I save the textcontent of the focused textarea in a variable and want to add it to the editor as html. After confirming the html-code shall be saved in the focused textarea. If I would use set content instead it would mean chaos... :(

Comment: yes, this is possible: tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(content, {format : 'raw'});

Comment: thx for the fast response! Now I use tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(text, {format : 'raw'}); to add the focused textareas html-content to the modal editor and j('#' + id).html(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent({format : 'raw'})); to overwrite the focused textarea's content with the modified text. I also disabled the auto-p-tagging with force_br_newlines : true,
                    force_p_newlines : false,
                    forced_root_block : '' but there seems to be an encoding error because the wysiwyg displays: <ul><li>Verdi 2</li><li>fgjgdhkgj<br data-mce-bogus="1"></li></ul> and the ...

Comment: ... html view just: &lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt;Verdi 2&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;fgjgdhkgj&lt;br data-mce-bogus="1"&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ul&gt;

Comment: another way to securely overcome this abstable is to reset the editor body by hand: $(editor.getBody()).html(content)

Comment: thx again. but with j(tinymce.activeEditor.getBody()).html(text); [j because of noconflict()] and j('#' + id).html(j(tinymce.activeEditor.getBody()).html()); it's still the same. That's strange. Where does that encoding come from?

Comment: Think I found something, but not tested yet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/html-encoding-in-javascript-jquery With these encoding/decoding functions it could work ;)

Comment: indeed, j(tinymce.activeEditor.getBody()).html(htmlDecode(text)); did the trick :) Thx for your help again!!!

Comment: glad to have been able to help